# How can I compute a 3D picking ray from 2D screen coordinates?

Tags: picking

I have a view matrix via glm. I want to make a ray casting system that receive an X and Y coordinate from the screen and generates a ray in the world. What math is needed?

My view matrix is built with this function:

```
glm::mat4 Camera::cameraViewMatrix()
{
    glm::mat4 matrix;


    matrix = glm::rotate(matrix, glm::radians(pitch),     {1, 0, 0});
    matrix = glm::rotate(matrix, glm::radians(yaw),       {0, 1, 0});
    matrix = glm::rotate(matrix, glm::radians(roll),      {0, 0, 1});

    matrix = glm::translate(matrix, glm::vec3(position.x, position.y + height, position.z)*-1.f);

    int width, height;
    SDL_GetWindowSize(display.GetWindow(), &width, &height);

    return glm::perspective(glm::radians(fov), (float)width/(float)height, 0.001f, 1000.f) * matrix;
}
```

I'd like to use this to select objects under the cursor.

Comment: Related, but also unanswered: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48831/how-to-create-3d-picking-ray-with-the-cursor-position. I'm surprised not to find a good dupe target for this question, since it's a very common problem, but most of the relevant questions are overly specific to certain scenarios or contexts.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I looked and remembered my mistakes. But I think I found a mistake "an X" that would be "a". Aboit this rau casting, I think the best would be glm::unproject, normalize the vector and see if it worked. If it worked I would leave a answer with it. Thanks again for heling me unserstanding my grammar mistakes.